# Azure Data Factory Escape Characters In String Values

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I've got a pipeline built in Azure Data Factory that's pulling data from SQL and storing it as csv.  My Dataset for the csv has Escape Character set to a blackslash `(\)` and Quote Character set to Double Quote `(")`.  The problem this causes is when I have an empty string with just a backslash, which unfortunately exists in my data quite a bit. Dozens of tables with many columns.

When this happens ADF outputs the backslash as `"\"` which then can't be interpreted from other systems to load.  The second quote is ignored because it's being escaped and it becomes just a single quote and it throws off the columns.  I have tried using other characters such as `"^"` to escape.  But I also have `"^"` in many values across many table columns and the same issue can happen.

It seems whenever an escape character exists in data that is at the end of a value (or the only value) it will cause an error.  How can I handle this without having to address it on the source side? Why doesn't data Factory convert escape characters to double backslash when it's in data? I would expect a string that's `"\"` to get converted to `"\\"` but it isn't happening.  Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

[image: Azure Data Factory File Settings]

Comment: Is it possible to share what the COPY INTO statement that is produced by ADF looks like based on the settings you are using from the front-end?  Do you have any values that need to be escaped in your data?  What happens if you just don't specify an escape character?

Comment: COPY INTO DEV_STAGING.<Schema>.<Table> (<Columnlist>) FROM @MyStage/<Directory>/2020/10/01/FileName pattern='.*.csv' FILE_FORMAT = DEV_STAGING.PUBLIC.BLOB_CSV;

Error:
Found character '0' instead of field delimiter ',' File '<filename>_v2_20201001T123000.csv', line 148120, character 104 Row 148119, column "<filename>"["$10":10] If you would like to continue loading .....

Comment: @MikeWalton
I don't think this is an issue with Snowflake, but rather how ADF is formatting data when an escape character exists in a string that is being quoted.  I am testing to see if not using quoting will work.

Also, I do have values that need to be escaped. I am migrating a project from ADLS gen1 to gen2 and in gen1 ADF allowed you to use quoting without escape characters and everything worked. But now they force you to use both escape character and quoting if you use quoting, which is causing the issue.

Comment: I tested not quoting the data in ADF and it resolved the escape character issues, but it created an issue with Snowflake not interpreting empty strings correctly.  Because I am not quoting strings it thinks an empty string value is a Null and fails the column constraint.  so it's interpreting ,, to euqal ,NULL,
Any thoughts @MikeWalton. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I think you'd need to explicitly use a IFNULL function, which would force you to use a SELECT in your COPY INTO statement.  I don't know whether ADF's interface allows you to do that, but that's how I think you need to get the COPY INTO to work.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I think I have an option by not using Quote Character and then handling the nulls in the source queries but it's not an ideal solution.  I think this is more a bug in Data Factory and I'm hoping to get a response from their support. It doesn't make sense to me why they aren't escaping the escape character automatically when it's put in a quote, but it does when it's outside of quotes.